# Consecutive numbers written as a large integer

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics

The question i was given by a friend is stated as follows.  I think there is an error.

> Write the first n positive integers from left to right in their natural order to form a large integer:
>   $$123456789101112 · · · n.$$
>   Suppose that this large number has 6927 digits. Find the value of n. Justify your answer.

So counting off the first 9 digits leaves $6918$ digits remaining.

Counting off the next $180=2\cdot 90$ digits leaves $6738$ digits remaining.

Counting off the next $2,700=3\cdot 900$ digits leaves $4038$ digits remaining.

There is my problem. So $n$ has to be a $4$-digit number, and so dividing by $4000$ tells me that i only have 38 digits to go, and so the number has to be 2009, but this would require 40 digits not 38.

I would thing then maybe they were asking for the actual last number (1's digit) in this huge integer, but the fact that we are writing the first $n$ number seequentially, and since $4038$ is not divisible by $4$ makes me think this problem is incorrect.  Thoughts?

EDIT:  So i guess my confusion is over the $n$.  Is $n=0$ or are they asking for the $n$th digit string (2009) here?

Comment: Your solving is correct. I think it is only asking for the number $2009$ because is we the digit $6927°$ is found. They made a bad statement.

Comment: That is what I thought.  I envisioned there was a brief miscalculation or a typo and it should have read $6929$ digits.

Answer (score 1):

Or are they asking for n such that "6927" is within the resulting number?

For that interpretation, I think the lowest n is 270 (n = 927 works also).

Comment: I'm going to say that is not what they were after, but i do think that is an interesting problem.

Comment: You are probably right but please let me know if you find out.  The initial "6" and the final "7" just seemed a little coincidental.